# Where is the location of cutin or cuticle in the plant leaf

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, structural-biology

Cutin's main role is to prevent the the plant leaf from water loss, cutin is thick in shape , but I need to know where is the location of it ,for example is it in the lower epidermis or in the upper epidermis ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Answer (score 1):

Cutin is a waxy substance comprised of a mixture of two or more [oliphatic acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_hydroxy_acid). It is secreted onto the whole above-ground surface of the plant: leaves, stem, flower-buds. As such, it covers the whole of the outside of the plant - excepting the [stomatic openings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoma) which serve to enable wanted moisture loss.

It's secreted by the epidermal layers of the tissues and has served to enable the plants to evolve beyond the marine environment in which they originated [in excess of 450 million years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_cuticle#Evolution). It provides a hydrophobic coating, preventing unwanted moisture-loss from the plant.

Cuticle is the name given to the coating of the leaves, cutin to the chemical mixture it comprises.